# Как объединить 2 таблицы, что бы что условие по второй было не обязательное?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Помогите построить запрос.
Вот таблицы:

##### Attr

| code | user_code | attr_code | attr_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 8 | 1 |
| 2 | 24 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 24 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 24 | 2 | 1 |

##### Users

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | Bolodya |

Этот запрос

```
select * from Users join Attr on Users.code = Attr.user_code 
where Users.code = 24 and Attr.attr_code = 8;
```

выдаст искомую строку только если в таблице attr есть запись с attr_code = 8 и user_code = 24. Мне же нужно, чтобы поля из таблицы Users выводились в любом случае, а поля из Attr только если есть запись с attr_code = 8(если таковой нет - на месте этих полей будет просто пустота).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте **left join** и в условие объединения таблиц добавьте `Attr.attr_code = 8`

```
select * from Users 
LEFT join Attr on Users.code = Attr.user_code and Attr.attr_code = 8
where Users.code = 24;
```

Comment: Спасибо 0_0 уже второй раз выручаете меня